# Problem on elementary logic and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let A and B be sets with B is a subset of A. Prove that A \ (A\B)=B.

I start by saying that suppose x is in A \ (A\B). By definition, x is in A and X is not in (A\B) . However, x is not in A\B does not mean that x is not in A and automatically in B.
I also do not know how to prove the opposite inclusion.

Comment: Why don't you prove it instead, or at least say what you've tried?

Comment: I would not post the question here if I had known how to do it

Comment: I don't expect you to know how to do it, but I (and other users of this site) expect you to put forth some effort in giving us what things you've tried to do and where they've gone wrong, instead of expecting us to just solve problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but surely a good way to do this(and understand) is by using Venn-diagrams:[image]

A more elegant, "written" proof. We prove, that the two sides are equivalent.

Suppose, that arbitrary $x \in A\setminus(A\setminus B)$. Then $x\in A$, and $x \notin (A\setminus B)$. If $x\notin (A\setminus B)$, then $x \notin A$, or $x \in B$. But we already supposed, that $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$, and $x \in B$, and $B \subseteq A, x \in B$.

Comment: But I need a written proof!

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi I appreciatethe reply but here is my problem: "If x∉ A\B, then x∉A and x∈B." Lets say x is in the green circle. In that case, x∉ A\B: x is in A and x is in B.

Comment: If $x$ isn't in the green circle, then it is in the orange ciricle(it can't be $x \in$ A\B anymore), and therefore $x \in $ A\B.

Comment: "If x∉ A\B, then x∉A and x∈B." Lets say x is in the green circle. In that case, x∉ A\B, but x is still in A and x is in B.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, x is still in A, I will correct it. :)

Comment: So here is my question: "x∈(A∖B)C=(B∖A)" may not always hold

Comment: Corrected it, hopefully it works.

Comment: The third sentence of your written proof is incorrect: if $x\notin A\setminus B$, then $x\notin A$ **or** $x\in B$. You have **and** instead of the correct **or**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

For the other inclusion: suppose $x \in B$. Then we know that $x \in A$, as $B \subseteq A$. But $x \notin A \setminus B$, because if it were, it would imply that $x \notin B$, which we know is false.

So $x \in A$, $x \notin A \setminus B$, so by definition $x \in A \setminus (A \setminus B)$.